# Codigniter Update query does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

the problem that i have is in this model. The query runs correctly if i remove the `where` statement, but i need the where statement in order to change one row depending on the id. when i run the query with the where statement i have no errors but not any affected row in the database.

```
 public function update_goods()
 {
   $id=$this->input->post('ID');
   $data=array(
     'ID'=>$this->input->post('ID'),
     'Title'=>$this->input->post('Title'),
     'Value'=>$this->input->post('Value'),
     'Description'=> $this->input->post('Description'),

  );

  $this->db->where('ID', $id);
  $this->db->update('goods',$data);


 }
```

Comment: Try to echo out $id . Are you getting the ID ?

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); - try this at the end of your update query.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine based on [the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update).

```
$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name'  => $name,
               'date'  => $date
            );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data); 

// Produces:
// UPDATE mytable 
// SET title = '{$title}', name = '{$name}', date = '{$date}'
// WHERE id = $id
```

I think you should take the ID from your array, though it doesn't need to be updated.

```
 public function update_goods()
 {
   $data = array(
     'Title'       => $this->input->post('Title'),
     'Value'       => $this->input->post('Value'),
     'Description' => $this->input->post('Description'),

   );
   $this->db->where('ID', $this->input->post('ID'));
   $this->db->update('goods', $data);
 }
```

Also, verify `$this->input->post('ID')` refers to a record in the `goods` table.

Comment: Thank you my friend, but my problem was different, I had a hidden input in my form and that input did not pass the id...

Comment: Haha, well notice my last point in the answer ;) Glad to hear you figured it out.